# Plot a tripartite Graph with its groups separated

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I would like to create a `Graph` like the following:

[image]

but without edges between vertices in the same group.

So I have a graph and I want to plot it such that its vertices are separated into 3 groups away from each other, I prefer that each group is not in line form, but better to be in random form.

Comment: no no, I mean that since it is a tripartite, there will be no edges between vertices inside each group. Anyway I just want to plot a graph and separate it into 3 groups in different locations

Comment: You should clarify your question and maybe provide an example of the desired output :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update 2:** Hiding the edges within the same community for general (not-necessarily tri-partite) graphs:

```
ClearAll[insideEdges]
insideEdges[g_, c_]:=Select[EdgeList[g], Or @@ (Function[x, SubsetQ[x, {##}] ]/@c)& @@ #&]
```

**Examples:**

```
zkc = ExampleData[{"NetworkGraph", "ZacharyKarateClub"}];

CommunityGraphPlot[zkc,  CommunityRegionStyle -> {LightRed, LightGreen, LightBlue},
 EdgeStyle -> {Alternatives @@ insideEdges[zkc, FindGraphCommunities[zkc]] :> Opacity[0]}]
```

[image]

```
dsn= ExampleData[{"NetworkGraph", "DolphinSocialNetwork"}];

CommunityGraphPlot[dsn,  CommunityRegionStyle -> 97,
 EdgeStyle -> {Alternatives @@ insideEdges[dsn, FindGraphCommunities[dsn]] :> Opacity[0]}]
```

[image]

**Update 1:**

```
athreepartitegraph = CompleteGraph[{10, 7, 3}, 
  GraphLayout -> {"MultipartiteEmbedding",  "VertexPartition" -> {10, 7, 3}},
  ImageSize -> 400, VertexLabels -> "Name", ImagePadding -> 20];

cgp = CommunityGraphPlot[athreepartitegraph, 
       {Range[10], Range[11, 17], Range[18, 20]}, Method -> "Hierarchical"];
Row[{athreepartitegraph, cgp}]
```

[image]

or

```
CommunityGraphPlot[athreepartitegraph, 
  {Range[10], Range[11, 17], Range[18, 20]}, Method -> "SpringElectrical"]
```

[image]

to compare with alternative vertex layouts:

```
Row[SetProperty[athreepartitegraph, 
    GraphLayout -> #] & /@ {{"CircularEmbedding"}, 
      {"CircularMultipartiteEmbedding", "VertexPartition" -> {10, 7, 3}}}]
```

[image]

---

**Original post:**

Maybe something like:

```
g2 = ExampleData[{"NetworkGraph", "ZacharyKarateClub"}];
g2 = SetProperty[g2, {VertexLabels -> "Name", ImagePadding -> 20, ImageSize -> 400}];

fgp = FindGraphPartition[GraphComplement[g2], 3];
mpg = Graph[Flatten@fgp, EdgeList[g2], 
   GraphLayout -> {"MultipartiteEmbedding", "VertexPartition" -> (Length /@ fgp)},
   VertexLabels -> "Name", 
   ImagePadding -> 20, ImageSize -> 400];

Row[{g2, mpg}]
```

[image]

```
CommunityGraphPlot[g2, fgp, Method -> "Hierarchical"]
```

[image]

Comment: I tried that, but I don't want the vertices to be in lines because I will use large graphs

Comment: @Ahned, if the layout is the issue, does something like `CommunityGraphPlot[g2, fgp, Method -> "Hierarchical"]` give something closer to what you need?

Comment: yes the layout is the problem but I need to make my own groups

Comment: @kguler the original and the update are very instructive beyond question...thank you again +1 :)

Comment: @ubpdqn, i appreciate the kind words.